# My gnr ts702 mr17e-aaad monitor isn't working on the maximum resolution

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution, vga, dvi

I hope this question isn't inappropriate, and I write it to the right webpage.

I have the monitor mentioned above. I used this monitor for long, and it worked on its maximum resolution (1280*1024), with the following setup: I had an Nvidia Geforce graphics card which had an HDMI and a DVI-I connector. But I didn't have any DVI cable, so I used a dvi to vga adapter, and then I connected the monitor with vga cable to it; in this setup my monitor worked properly.

Afterwards I bought a whole new PC, with a processor that has graphics card inside it - Amd Ryzen 5 3400G with radeon vega 11 graphics - and a motherboard - ASRock b450 pro4-f - that has vga, dvi-d and hdmi connector too. Installed the graphics driver, bought a dvi-d cable, connected the monitor (which supports dvi-d according to specifications) with the dvi-d cable to the pc, and it had a maximum resolution of about 800*600 despite of the dvi-i connector and everything. In the windows 10 settings app, below display settings it only appears as it is the maximum resolution and I can't set bigger.

Can someone help to set the monitor to its real highest resolution? Thank you in advance.